# Can I working with remote git repository and don't clone this on local via GitPython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I need to make some git actions (e.g. commit, push, pull..) without cloning a repo on local via GitPython. Is there a way to do this or I must to use a path to my .git dir ?

Answer (score 0):

Platforms like Github or GitLab for instance, propose tools to directly change your code online on their website. Would this be a solution for you?